# Find all geolocations in a bounding box

Tags: mysql, database-design, geolocation, database-schema, bounding-box

I have a MySQL table (with about ~100.000 entries) like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `poi` (
  `poi_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `lat` decimal(10,6) default NULL,
  `lng` decimal(10,6) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`poi_id`),
  KEY `lat` (`lat`),
  KEY `lng` (`lng`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Basically all I want to do with these entries is to get all POIs which are in a given bounding box (bbox).

What would be a good (fast but not too complicated) way to achieve this?

Changing the database schema (and even the DBMS) is an option for me if that brings any benefits. I doubt that my naive schema is a fast approach.

BTW: I've already read about PostGIS but I don't really such complexity. So I'd rather stick to a simple and clean solution.

Comment: "fast but not too complicated" -- those two requirements are at odds with each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM poi
WHERE lat >= @lat - @degrees 
AND lat <= @lat + @degrees
AND lng >= @lng - @degrees
AND lng <= @lng + @degrees
```

Of course, you could also pass upper and lower parameters for lat and lng which may be more efficient

Comment: The "box" is somewhat like a rectangle, not a square.  In the lng tests, divide by `cos(@lat)`.

Comment: Peter, did my quick solution for narrowing down your POI list help?